# State value goes empty to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management

I'm trying to send information from parent to child component with a state.

In the parent component, I'm getting the value and storing it inside an array named valueArray. Later on, this array will be stored in a state and sent through child component to map and display the values.

1-) Function below takes the values selected by user and pushes them inside an empty array valueArray.

```
let valueArray = [];
    const getSelectedItem = (event) =>{

        if(valueArray.includes(item)){
            valueArray.splice(item.index,1);
           
        }else{
            valueArray.push(item);
        }
       
    }
```

2-) In here, after user done with selecting values, another function to store values in state will be initiated by onClick, this function uses valueArray as argument.

```
<button onClick={() => handleState(valueArray)}>Buton</button>
```

3-) After the button click, handleState function executes and updates state with the elements in valueArray, ***values*** array goes to child component to map and perform display.

```
    const [values,setValues] = useState([]);
    const handleState = (arr) =>{
            setValues([...arr])     
    }
```

***Major problem in here is, when button clicked at the first time after selection, state becomes empty array and child  component can't execute mapping because valueArray's initial value is []. Second click works and state changes with values inside the valueArray.***

Comment: valueArray also you need to maintain in state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use State like this.

```
 const [valueArray, setValueArray] = [];
    const getSelectedItem = (event) =>{
    const array = [...valueArray]; 
        if(array.includes(item)){
            array.splice(item.index, 1);
            // setValueArray([...valueArray.filter((ite) => ite != item)]);
            setValueArray([...array]);
           
        }else{
            // valueArray.push(item);
             setValueArray([...array, item]); // instead of push we should use spread or concat()
        }
       
    }
```